# Skip "Select a Network" during Chromebook setup

Tags: wireless-networking, setup, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I purchased a Toshiba Satellite Chromebook for testing and evaluation of [ChromeOS](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os). On the first screen I am prompted to select a network. The image below is from HP docs because Toshiba does not provide instructions with images and I don't have full access to the machine yet:

[image]

There appears to be an incompatibility at the moment because I keep getting a "Bad Password" error when attempting to connect to my Wifi access point. I've tried it about 6 times and even had someone else verify the password I entered.

I'd like to proceed without connecting to the Wifi network. According to the Chromebook FAQ, this is a valid configuration because the device works offline (*cf*., [Do Chromebooks work offline?](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3265094?hl=en&ref_topic=3399709)). However, the ***Continue*** button is disabled when I select ***No Network***.

How do I skip "Select a Network" during Chromebook setup?

Comment: They work offline yes, but accounts are all google accounts so you may not be able to use the device without a first time connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047362?hl=en), you must have a network (internet) connection available to set up your Chromebook.

> To set up your Chromebook, you'll need:
>
> - Your Google Account username and password
> - Access to a Wi-Fi network. Some Chromebooks also support Ethernet.

*After* you have set up your chromebook, then you may use if offline (although functionality becomes limited in some respects, to be expected of course).

Comment: Thanks. I had to purchase a USB/Ethernet adapter because of a bug in the damn OS. Its not surprising they fail to disclose these things when you buy the equipment...